# Tag edits no longer have quick wiki access

Tags: bug, tags, edits, tag-excerpt

Recently behaviour has changed when editing tags on https://stackoverflow.com & https://meta.stackoverflow.com after clicking 'edit' for the whole post or 'Edit tags' for just the tags. There is no longer a tag wiki excerpt. This makes it difficult to tag properly.

(The tag wiki excerpt still shows in the tag mouseover popup.)

Add-ons Disabled:

[image: meta.so edit screenshot, no wiki]

[image: meta.so Edit tags screenshot, no wiki]

The old behaviour still happens on https://meta.stackexchange.com and (say) https://skeptics.stackexchange.com.

[image: meta.so edit screenshot, wiki]

(Not that the old behaviour was ideal, since one could not directly go to the tag wiki page for more information, preferably in a new tab.)

Comment: I cannot repro what you describe, either here on Meta or on main. I have the exact same configuration (Windows 10, Firefox 78.0.1, 64-bit).

Comment: @CodyGray See screen shots--2 bad meta.so, 1 normal meta.se.

Comment: No repro on Firefox Nightly 80.0a1, Arch Linux. Do you get any errors or warnings in the console or in the Network tab of your dev tools?

Comment: @user4642212 No add-ons web console on page load: `The resource at “<URL>” was blocked because content blocking is enabled. 3` >> `The resource at “https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js” was blocked because content blocking is enabled. tag-edits-no-longer-have-quick-wiki-access The resource at “https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js” was blocked because content blocking is enabled. tag-edits-no-longer-have-quick-wiki-access The resource at “https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js” was blocked because content blocking is enabled. tag-edits-no-longer-have-quick-wiki-access` Still bug.

Comment: @user4642212 Then turning off Firefox 'enhanced tracking protection' for the site & loading: `Some cookies are misusing the recommended “sameSite“ attribute 7` >> `Cookie “_dlt” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite` & messages for 6 other cookies. Still bug.

Comment: Nomenclature thing: That's the tag excerpt (a.k.a., User guidance) that's showing, not the tag wiki. I expect everyone understands what you're talking about though, hence I'm not editing and just commenting in case you want to edit :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I did research to find tag wiki 'summary' used somewhere jn the documentation. I see on the tag wiki editing page there is tag wiki 'info' mentioned & 'usage guidance' that is somehow an '(excerpt)' & a bigger box of editable stuff which is maybe the 'wiki' or the part of the 'wiki' or 'info' that isn't the 'excerpt' & that a help page asks 'What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?' but frankly the disorganized search-engine anti-manual attitude of SO Inc documentation is such a mess that I just stopped when I found one term.

Comment: Too true on the SO Inc docs... "excerpt" and "wiki" are just the terms I've heard most often in meta discussions over the years, but I've certainly not been in all of them. As I say, I think everyone knows what you're talking about.

Comment: @HereticMonkey [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) link [What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337) answer: "Each tag on Stack Exchange has two pieces of user-editable content associated with it: • a short tag wiki **excerpt** of up to about 500 characters of plain text, and • a **full tag wiki** page describing the tag in more detail." "The tag wiki excerpt is shown: [...] • in the menu of available tags shown when a user is adding tags to a question."

Comment: @HereticMonkey But that's immediately followed by 'A "learn more" link, shown alongside the excerpt, points to the "info" tab for the tag, which shows the full tag wiki. This is also the place where both the excerpt and the full tag wiki can be edited.' Where under a heading 'About' there is a smaller heading 'Tag Info' & then 'A "tag wiki" is an editable page [...]'. Uhhhnn ... PS Thanks.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325627). Entering and exiting the mobile site in the footer fixed it for me.